# Using ELK in Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, elk, observability

We are using Azure App Insights for all tracing . monitoring and log requirements of our applications running in Azure.

We have seen cases where teams ship the logs to ELK for observability. We do not see any additional benefit of using ELK over Azure App Insights .

https://medium.com/@cloudgeek/sending-logs-from-azure-app-services-to-elk-simplify-log-management-and-analysis-b95d67bc46b1

https://www.bing.com/search?q=stack+overflow&cvid=898822cf2f75426e885b306e1235b92f&aqs=edge.1.69i57j46j0l4j69i65l3j69i11004.2817j0j9&FORM=ANAB01&PC=U531

Let me know if there are any scenarios where ELK will be a better fit than Azure App Insights.

We are already using Azure App Insights and would like to know if there is any merit in migrating to ELK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any benefit in terms of features. Azure Application Insights will give you visibility not only on your app, but also the infrastructure.

Some companies / teams already use different stacks (such as ELK) to monitor on premises apps. So that's probably one of the reasons they want to stick with that, a single place to monitor on-premises/Azure applications.

Another reason is the price. Depending on the amount of information you store, Azure Application Insights can be expensive and other companies may prefer to use a different tool.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are right. These are the factors . We are also using ELK on prem and there are benefits in having a common logging solution across enterprise ( GCP, Azure & On Prem) . Cost is another factor. But to have a reliable ELK in Azure, we need to have intermdiary Kafka component as well .  Hence we did not see a huge cost difference between the ELK and Azure App Insights